# Please assist in developing a Python decorator

Tags: python, function

DESCRIPTION

Implement a Python decorator that should take whatever the decorated function returns, and write it to a file in a new line. For the sake of this problem, let us assume that the decorated functions always return a string. The decorator should be named log_message and should write to the file /tmp/decorator_logs.txt.

Implement the following design

```py
@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_a_string():

      return "A string"

@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_a_string_with_newline(s):

      return "{}\n".format(s)

@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_another_string(string=""):

            return "Another string"
```

Comment: We're not here to do your hw, but we can help you get there. Please post what you've tried so far

Comment: You seem to be assigning us homework. Typically work-for-hire programming isn't free -- what's your budget?

Comment: @M Z - I have defined my function as decorator which does return "@log_message"

Comment: Adam Smith - A bit of advice would help. I am not asking you to do the work.

Comment: def decorator():

      return "@log_message"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the decorator:

```py
def log_message(func):
    def wrap(*args,**kwargs):
        res = func(*args,**kwargs)
        with open('/tmp/decorator_logs.txt','wt') as f:
            f.write(res)
        return res
    return wrap
```

But from your description of what you did in your comments, it seems that you don't fully understand the decorator concept.

You can think of `decorator` as a special function that takes another function as input and return a decorated function that do something slightly different.

In the code above, `log_message` take what ever function it decorates, and define a new function called `wrap`. This `wrap` function take whatever inputs, pass those input arguments to func, write the returned result of func to the `tmp/decorator_logs.txt` file, then return the same result.

Another thing you need to understand is that

```py
@log_message
def decorated_function():
    ....
```

is the same as:

```py
decorated_function = log_message(decorated_function)
```

Hope this help with your understanding of `decorator`.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Very helpful, I completely understand.